# Jquery when input field is empty set both input fields to disable false

Tags: javascript, jquery

When something is typed in the url field and it is cleared again. Both input fields should be set to disable false.

The code is live here: http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/117/

My HTML:

```
<h1>Upload image:</h1>
<input type="file" name="blog[opload]" id="blog_opload" class="imagec">
<input type="url" size="50" name="blog[url]" id="blog_url" class="imagec">
<div id="preview">
</div>
```

My JQUERY:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    $('.imagec').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    alert( $(this).text() );
    if ( $(this).attr('type') == 'url') {
        $('#preview').show().html('<img src=' + '"' + $(this).val() + '"' + ' />');
    }
});

 if( !$('.imagec').trim(this.value).length ) {
          alert('TOM');
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This :**

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if(this.value === ""){
        $('.imagec').prop('disabled', false);
        this.disabled = false;
        $('#preview').hide();
    }else{
        $('.imagec').prop('disabled', true);
        el.prop('disabled', false);
        alert( el.val() );
        if (el.attr('type') == 'url') {
            $('#preview').show().html('<img src=' + '"' + el.val() + '"' + ' />');
        }   
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**

See Feedle : **[http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/aikosystems/buyC9/121/)**

Comment: Try to type something in the url field. And then clear it. The upload field is still disabled

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.imagec').change(function() {
    $('.imagec').prop('disabled', true);
    var iAm = $(this);
    iAm.removeProp('disabled');
    if (iAm.val() == "") {
        $('.imagec').removeProp('disabled');
    }
    alert($(this).val());
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'url') {
        $('#preview').show().html('<img src=' + '"' + $(this).val() + '"' + ' />');
    }
});
```